# C basic infinite loop MVS that calculates avarege with neighbors

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, infinite-loop

So this is supposed to be realy basic, and im almost sure im missing something becuase I managed write more complex codes...

The codes is supposed to take a positive intigers and write the avarage of each number with its neighbors, the integers given by the user would be at least 2 integers.

so if the user gives a1 a2 a3 a4
the output would be "(a1+a2)/2, (a1+a2+a3)/3,(a2+a3+a4)/3,(a3+a4)/2"
but its not limited to 4 numbers, it could be less or more.

The problem is that when I have only a1 a2 the out put is (a1 +a2)/2, (a1 + a2)/2
The code is supposed to know if theres an a3 or not and then decide how to calculate the second one?
I'm sure I'm missing something here and I have no clue...
I'm not supposed to use anything more than basic, I've written something that calculates a1 and a2 in case theres only to inputs (a1,a2)
but it's obviously wrong since the code won't work for a1, a2, a3 and so on...

I'm putting the code although it's not close to the solution and is not polished even for what it does:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float num=0.0,num2=-1, nextnum=-1,nextnext=-1, after=0.0,after2=0.0;
    do {
        scanf("%f", &num);
        if (num2==-1)
        {
            scanf("%f", &num2);

        after=num+num2  ;   

        nextnum=num2;
        printf("%4g" , (after/2) );
        }


        after=num+nextnum   ;   


        nextnum=num;


    printf("%4g" , (after/2));

    }           
    while (num>0);
    return 0;

}
```

any kind of help/suggestion/guidence would be gladly accepted..

Comment: have you tried using the debugger to see what is happening?

Comment: I know what is happening, the code works for a1 and a2, I'ts not supposed to work for more becuase I have no idea what to ask for...

Comment: The variable names don't help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, i'd sugest you write a table of your variables and their values after each itteration. I did it for 3 itterations and it only does the avarage of each 2 numbers. I don't know if this is your original code or only part of it, because you are not even using `nextnext` nor `after2` variables.
But to solve your original problem you should add an `else` block for your `if`, and add any necessary instructions to the if part.
A possible solution could be:

```
do {
    scanf("%f", &num);
    if (num2==-1)
    {
        scanf("%f", &num2);

    after=num+num2  ;   

    nextnum=num;
    nextnext = num2;
    printf("%4g" , (after/2) );
    }
    else {

    after=num+nextnum+nextnext   ;   

    nextnext=nextnum;
    nextnum=num;


    printf("%4g" , (after/2));
    }

}           
while (num>0);
```

That should do it for averages to the last 3 numbers, you may add the part for the last 2 numbers after the `while` cicle with `nextnum` and `nextnext` wich should contain the last 2 inputed numbers after the cicle.